# Tensorflow: Error initializing variables created within tf.data.Dataset.map()

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets

I have created a function with TF operations that I invoke with `tf.data.Dataset.map()` to transform the input data to my model. Inside that function I create a `tf.Variable` and assign to it. When initializing the variables, TF complains that the variable's init operation is not an element of the graph, or that the variable does not belong to the same graph as the other variables. I would appreciate any help to solve this issue.

Here you can see some toy code to reproduce the issue (TF 1.12):

```
import tensorflow as tf

def fun(x):
    f = tf.Variable(tf.ones((1,), dtype=tf.int64), name='test')
    op = f.assign(x, name='test_assign')
    with tf.control_dependencies([op]):
       f = tf.identity(f)
    return f

def generator():
  while True:
    yield [2]

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, 
output_shapes=tf.TensorShape([1,]), output_types=tf.int64)
ds = ds.map(fun)
iterator = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
y = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  
for _ in range(5):
   print(sess.run(y)
```